# 301 Redirect all files ending in .cfm

Tags: apache, redirect

I am trying to redirect all .cfm pages on my server to a specific page, so all pages in all subdirectories, I can't seem to get it working, here is what I have thus far.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(*.cfm) http://www.yoursite.com/
```

I have very little experience concerning this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this
RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*).cfm$ http://www.yoursite.com/